# Compare screen size with current root window size

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I use tkinter to create a GUI. Inside the root window, there are some widgets and a canvas. The user can Control the size of the canvas.

What  I want to do:
When the total size of the main root does not fit in the Screen, the canvas will stop extending (stop getting bigger) and will be scrollable.

The Problem:
I don't know how to compare the values together. How can I get the current root size as integers?

Is this a good approach or are there any better solutions?

What I tried:

```
root.winfo_screenwidth() and root.winfo_screenheight() #to get Screen size.

root.winfo_geometry() or root.geometry() #to get the current size of the root as a string in %sx%s+0+0 format.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `root.geometry()` to solve this problem. Try `root.winfo_width()` and `root.winfo_height()` instead:

```py
# the code before checking size
if root.winfo_width() * root.winfo_height() < root.winfo_screenwidth() * root.winfo_screenheight():
    # the code to do when the main root doesn't fit in the Screen
# the code after checking size
```